# How to solve: ValueError: Invalid format specifier?

Tags: python, printing, format

```
h=1
m=1
s=30
k=5
ks = ((h * 60) + m + (s / 60)) / k
s=(ks - int(ks)) * 0.6
print(f'0{ks:.0f}:{s:.2f:.02}')
```

I am trying run the code, but i recieve the error: ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Comment: What's the`:.02` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ValueError: Invalid format specifier '.2f:.02' for object of type 'float'
```

This is the full error, simply you can't use `2f:.02` as specifier in brackets.

```
>>> print(f'0{ks:.0f}:{s:.2f}')
012:0.18
```

This is a sample output changing the specifier in brackets.